# How to include the "auth_request" module nginx?

Tags: ruby, nginx, heroku, buildpack

For some reason the "auth_request" directive is not found. I am using the `heroku-buildpack-nginx` with that change only to include the `--with-http_auth_request_module` in the **build_nginx** script.

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "auth_request" in ./config/nginx.conf
```

My nginx.conf:

```
daemon off;
# Heroku dynos have at least 4 cores.
worker_processes <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKERS'] || 4 %>;

events {
    use epoll;
    accept_mutex on;
    worker_connections <%= ENV['NGINX_WORKER_CONNECTIONS'] || 1024 %>;
}

http {
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 2;
    gzip_min_length 512;

    server_tokens off;

    log_format l2met 'measure#nginx.service=$request_time request_id=$http_x_request_id';
    access_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ACCESS_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/access.log' %> l2met;
    error_log <%= ENV['NGINX_ERROR_LOG_PATH'] || 'logs/nginx/error.log' %>;

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;

    # Must read the body in 5 seconds.
    client_body_timeout 5;

    upstream app_server {
        server unix:/tmp/nginx.socket fail_timeout=0;
    }

    server {
        listen <%= ENV["PORT"] %>;
        server_name _;
        keepalive_timeout 5;


        location / {
                auth_request /_oauth2_token_introspection;
                proxy_pass https://my-backend;
            }

        location = /_oauth2_token_introspection {
                internal;
                proxy_method      GET;
                proxy_set_header  Authorization "Bearer $token";
                proxy_set_header  Content-Type "application/json";
                proxy_pass        https://{myIDP};
            }
        }
}
```

And I've added the model to ./configure `--with-http_auth_request_module`:

```
# This will build `nginx`
(
cd nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}
./configure \
--with-pcre=pcre-${PCRE_VERSION} \
--with-zlib=zlib-${ZLIB_VERSION} \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--prefix=/tmp/nginx \
--add-module=${temp_dir}/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/headers-more-nginx-module-${HEADERS_MORE_VERSION} \
--add-module=${temp_dir}/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/nginx-uuid4-module-${UUID4_VERSION}
make install
)
```

Using NGINX_VERSION-1.18.0. Could you help me understand why this module is not found?

Comment: What is the `nginx -V` command output?

Comment: How to run this command in a heroku dyno?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the `heroku` tag. I thought you have some console access to the server. I don't know how to check the actually compiled modules in heroku.